# Preset Command is not found in Laravel 5.5

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5.5

I am installing React in Laravel 5.5, but I am facing an error that preset command is "not defined".

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>    Command "preset" is not defined.

How do I solve that issue?

Comment: How are you installing react?

Comment: https://appdividend.com/2017/08/31/laravel-5-5-reactjs-tutorial/ 

working according to that tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution. Looks like later version of Laravel stopped supporting certain UI features directly. See: https://dev.to/lossez/comment/m9df. To save a click, run:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

```
php artisan ui react
```

Looks like you might also have to add `Laravel\Ui\UiServiceProvider::class` to your config/app.php file for that artisan command to work.

Answer (score -1):

Check your current PHP version.

1. go to xampp
2. click on config in front of Apache
3. open php.ini
4. Check you php version.
5. change it to 7.1(according to your requirements)

Comment: This check list does not help in any way. Laravel 5.5 does not require php in version 7.1 according to documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#server-requirements